# In r over ssh, is there an easy way to detect the 'correct' local display for x11 programmatically?

Tags: r, ssh, x11, forwarding

My daily workflow involves sshing (with ssh -Y ...) into a linux cluster to compute in r. To keep my place, I use tmux to create persistent sessions for many reasons. Most of the time when I log in my local display will detach from the session. There's a rather simple, but annoying fix for this: detach tmux, type `xeyes` to make sure my local display is functioning, get `echo $DISPLAY`, go back into r and `Sys.setenv('DISPLAY' = ':12.0')` or whatever `echo $DISPLAY` returns.

This process is bothersome so I tried to create a function to put in my .Rprofile but to no avail. The goal is to somehow detect and change the local display that will actually open an x11 window with one line of code. Below is not a working example, but a framework for what I'm looking for:

```
resetDisplay <- function{
  # if system xeyes fails
  if(tryCatch(system('xeyes')){
    # for every possible local display
    for(i in 1:15){
      Sys.setenv('DISPLAY' = sprintf(':%d.0', i))
    }
  }
}

# call function to change displays
resetDisplay()
```

Any ideas? One thought I just had is, can you set a default local display for your ssh?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: perhaps you should take a look at `sudo apt-get install mosh` that substitutes stateless, encrypted UDP for SSH, which should take connectivity, my computer went to sleep (essentially state based differences out of the equation)...[mosh](https://mosh.org/), and I only know what little I know via this reddit remark [about using mosh](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/5s7i1h/how_to_keep_ssh_connections_alive/ddd1r9p?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3). HTH, though I liked slipping xeyes in the mix.

Comment: I've got a remote linux server with R, mosh, tmux. How do you do handling plotting?

Comment: I plot using xquartz and x11 on a mac, will try out mosh and see if that helps

Comment: An [OSX](https://blog.filippo.io/my-remote-shell-session-setup/) approach with `iTerm2`, i'm in linux.